# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter data fetching policy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Does FirebaseRecyclerAdapter load all children at a reference at once, or only upon scrolling. Suppose we have a ref containing thousands of chat messages, are they all going to be fetched from database at once??

Answer (score 0):

The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` loads whatever child nodes are matches by the `DatabaseReference` or `Query` you pass into it. It does not implement pagination or another form of load-on-demand.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 'pagination' is the keyword I was looking for.